# Do we need SCVMM in order to test Storage Spaces Direct in Windows Server 2016?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, system-center, scvmm, storage-spaces

I've installed in our lab three Windows Server 2016 Datacenter edition. Each server has five SAS drives and we'll purchase a few SSDs for the servers. Right now we are testing our infrastructure and we are looking at Storage Spaces in Windows Server 2016. So the question is, can we deploy Storage Spaces Direct with help of SCVMM? Also, do we actually need SCVMM?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Currently we suggest SCVMM to our customers only in cases of four and more nodes.

I can’t tell for sure whether you need SCVMM in your case, but our last customer with four servers and over 100 VMs is almost not using SCVMM.

For more information on configuration, these two topics were very helpful for us:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center-docs/vmm/scenario/storage-spaces-manage
https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/how-to-deploy-and-manage-storage-spaces-direct-cluster-using-scvmm-2016

Comment: IMO you can go with SCVMM as well as without it. But yeah, usually it is recommended for large amount of nodes.

Comment: What about a monitoring of s2d? Does it give you to setup some health monitors or specify alerts settings? or should I use something like 5nine manager for managing an entire cluster?

Answer (score 3):

SCVMM2016, PowerShell (that's what Microsoft pushes real hard), and there are some third-party products as well, but they are vendor locked-in so isn't really an option now.

Comment: please clarify in your answer whether SCVMM _can_ be used or _must_ be used.

Comment: CAN be used. You'll be fine with PowerShell only.